# Jquery add html() for individual elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm loading an ajax-loader gif whenever a voting button is clicked. The image however appears for all items. I'm trying to find out how to load the image just for the item I voted. This is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".vote").click(function(e) {
       $('.ajax_load').html('<img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
       var item_id = $(this).attr("id");
       var dataString = 'item_id=' + item_id;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "vote.php",
        data: dataString,  
        cache: false,
        success: function(html) {
     $('.ajax_load').html('Voted!');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

HTML sample

```
<div class="vote" id=88">Vote</div> <div class="ajax_load">
<div class="vote" id=92">Vote</div> <div class="ajax_load">
<div class="vote" id=38">Vote</div> <div class="ajax_load">
```

Comment: are there many items with class `ajax_load` ? If so we will need to see some HTML (*the structure*) so we can see how to filter to that specific item.. (*also, why are you using a vote tag selector ? seems invalid*)

Comment: Could you provide a sample of HTML so we can be sure what html you are using?

Comment: @Gaby I forgot to add the dot, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the html sample, it looks like the elements are siblings so you should use

```
$(this).nextAll('.ajax_load:first').html('<img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
```

to show the image.

in the success callback use

```
$('#' + item_id).nextAll('.ajax_load:first').html('Voted!');
```

to target the specific voted element.

Comment: Mate this works! Thank you! I'll look into the documentation and learn how your code functions

Answer (score 0):

Assuming .ajax_load is a child of vote, then you can change this:

```
$('.ajax_load').html('<img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
```

to:

```
   $(this).find('.ajax_load').html('<img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
```

That will only effect the `.ajax_load` that is a child of the vote that was clicked, and not all of them.

Same thing in your ajax call.  I believe `$(this)` should still refer to the clicked "vote".

```
$('.ajax_load').html('Voted!');
```

Becomes...

```
$(this).find('.ajax_load').html('Voted!');
```

**edit** Okay, given that html, there are a couple of ways to do this.  I would probably do it this way:

```
$(this).next('.ajax_load:first')...  <- do whatever you'll do with the selection.
```

Generally, if you're trying to figure out how to select a div using JQuery, a great place to look is the Jquery documentation for [traversing](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) and [selecting](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: Thanks for the code! This works perfectly for the .vote div but I'm loading the ajax-loader.gif in another div. I added some HTML sample

Comment: the code still doesn't work but I've found the links very useful! I think using jquery each will work

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there are several elements having the class `ajax_load`. You need to somehow identify them uniquely. Take a look at the explanations in these questions:

- [How to show a hidden div on mouse over on a series of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191149/how-to-show-a-hidden-div-on-mouse-over-on-a-series-of-images/4191172#4191172)
- [jquery individual mouseenter for elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4239178/jquery-individual-mouseenter-for-elements/4239195#4239195)

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
$("vote").click(function(e) {
    $(this).html(...);
}
```